# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('

Tags: php, parsing, syntax, preg-match-all, parse-error

I am trying, But I get an error

```
preg_match_all("#href='(.*?)' span class="meta-nav"(.*?)</span>#si",$sonuc[1],$sayfalar);
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\AppServ\www\wordpress\deneme\deneme.php on line 154

How should I write it?

Comment: Have you even read the code? You can see the problem just by the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Em, have you edited your question now just to make the syntax highlighting go away?

Comment: Wow,not even try to read how regex works,and ask for help here... What a lazy man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have doublequotes inside your regexp, you need to escape them, because they're terminating the string that contains the regexp.

```
preg_match_all("#href='(.*?)' <span class=\"meta-nav\">(.*?)</span>#si",$sonuc[1],$sayfalar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape your double quotes as :

```
preg_match_all("#href='(.*?)' <span class=\"meta-nav\">(.*?)</span>#si",$sonuc[1],$sayfalar);
```